# Resources on AWS EC2 Shared Tenancy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

For shared instance tenancy on AWS, I understand that it means multiple AWS accounts may share the same physical hardware.

My question is whether if other tenants can be running their workload concurrently on the same instance that you have provisioned and currently in running state?

My concerns are around compute with GPUs, specifically the g5.xlarge where there is only 1 GPU. Would that GPU and VRAM be shared amongst workload that run on the same physical hardware?